# Can't add to an array from a separate class

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


    HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);


    // create BarEntry for Bar Group 2
    bargroup2 = new ArrayList<>();

    // creating dataset for Bar Group2
    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(bargroup2, "Week 2");

    //barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    barDataSet2.setColor(Color.rgb(100, 50, 10));


    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("December");
    labels.add("November");
    labels.add("October");

    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
    dataSets.add(barDataSet2);


    // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets);
    barChart.setData(data);


    test("7");

return rootView;
}    
public void test(String time){
    String f = "f";
    Float timefFloat = Float.parseFloat(time + f);
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(timefFloat, 1));

}
```

When I call this method from the same class it successfully adds the BarEntry to my `bargroup2` array list which adds the data to my MPAndroidChart.

However when I call this method from a separate class it causes my app to stop. How can I fix this?

Comment: how do u store this array in your app ? and how dou you trying to reach it ?

Comment: You saw that you're not initialized the array right?

it will throw NPE if access from other class, since the onCreateView is call by the android cycle, just do a ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup2 = new ArrayList<>() , and you should be good.

Comment: try `barChart.invalidate()` at the end of your onCreateView()